# how to move rails app (including rvm settings) to new user, new development computer?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We have a working development setup on John's macbook (lion), with 5 rails apps. Each of our apps uses rvw, with an .rvmrc file something like:

```
environment_id="ruby-1.9.3-p429@pPROJECT_NAME_2013"
```

So John's mac has a .rvm folder with an entry in .rvm/gems for each project's current gemset. And the source is in a git repository.

Sam is taking over the project, has a new macbook (mavericks), with xcode, brew, rvm, postgres installed.

Can't use migration assistant (new user, and only only want to migrate the rails files).

Besides the five project directories, what do we move to Sam's machine to effectively move the development environment to Sam's machine, also accounting for any re-compiling of gems in gemsets that due to the OS change.

Moving the postgres data also would be nice, but not required. (We can recreate the development data easily enough.)

Comment: @meager "besides the five project directories" was the question. Eg, cp what? There seem to be lots of little hidden directories (such as ~/.rvm) which introduce some complex dependencies (like versions of ruby, specfic gemsets which might or might not need to be recompiled, etc.)

Comment: There should be literally nothing else, and even the `cp` should really be a `git clone`. After, `bundle`, as you would if you picked up literally any other Rails project from github. There should be no need to copy *anything* from one laptop to another for a new developer to start working on a project.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you versioned the code in a repository, there is very little you need to migrate other than the repository itself and the system dependencies (assuming your projects are using a recent version of Rails powered by Bundler).

- Install the system dependencies on the new machine (Ruby may be via RVM, PostgreSQL, etc)
- Clone the repository
- Run `$ bundle` to install the gem dependencies
- Create the database and restore the schema using `$ rake db:schema:load`
- You're ready to go

If you want to restore the data, dump the old database and import it on the other machine. You can skip the schema step if you import the dump.

Make sure the following setting files are versioned and included in the repository:

- `schema.rb`
- `.ruby-version` and `.ruby-gemset` for RVM
- `Gemfile` and `Gemfile.lock`

Comment: Thank you - much simpler than I anticipated. In my case, after cloning the repo on the new machine, we needed to run `rvm install ruby-1.9.3-p429` then `rvm gemset create PROJECTNAME_2013` then `rvm gemset use PROJECTNAME_2013`. then `cd` out of the directory, then `cd` back into the directory (so rvm kicks in. THEN run `bundle install`. Voila.